# document.querySelectorAll('*[id]') doesn't show all form fields ids in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

I am trying to connect js with django (because I am using js google maps api).
In the first line of JS I have written:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('*[id]'))
```

I obtain the following results:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvdgs.png)

I have this django's form:

```
from django import forms


class DateInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type='date'
    
class userRequest(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    lat_Origin = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id':'lat_Origin'}),required=False,initial=181)
    lon_Origin = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id':'lon_Origin'}),required=False,initial=181)
    lat_Dest = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id':'lat_Dest'}),required=False,initial=181)
    lon_Dest = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id':'lon_Dest'}),required=False,initial=181)

    origin_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'data_aux data','id':'origin_address'}))
    destination_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'data_aux data','id':'destination_address'}))

    date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'data_aux data','id':'data_id'}))
    #date2=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'data_aux data','id':'data_id2'}))

    maxPrice=forms.FloatField(label='Max price:',widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'data_aux data order','step': '0.1'}),required=False)

    CHOICES_ORDERTYPE =(
    ('NONE', 'NONE'),
    ('ASC', 'ASC'),
    ('DESC', 'DESC'),
    )
    
    OrderType = forms.ChoiceField(label='Order',choices = CHOICES_ORDERTYPE,initial='NONE',required=False,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'data order'}))

    CHOICES_ORDERBY =(
    ('PRICE', 'PRICE'),
    ('DURATION', 'DURATION'),
    )
    OrderBy = forms.ChoiceField(label='Order by',choices = CHOICES_ORDERBY,initial='PRICE',required=False,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'data order'}))
```

I don't know why lat_Origin, lon_Origin, lat_Dest, lon_Dest are not in **document.querySelectorAll('*[id]')**

Do you have some idea how to fix this ?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, open your element tab search for that element see if its there .